# NanoGallery2 - triggering lightbox automatically

Tags: jquery, nanogallery

Within a list of images (an album) - clicking will open the lightbox.
I want the lightbox triggered automatically, on page load.

This is my code, I am using the `"openOnStart": "ID1",` to target the first image

```
<div ID="ngy2p" data-nanogallery2='{
    "thumbnailWidth": "200",
    "thumbnailLabel": {
      "position": "overImageOnBottom",
      "display": false,
      "openOnStart": "ID1",
      "titleMultiLine": true,
      "descriptionMultiLine": true
    },
    "thumbnailHoverEffect2":  "imageScale150|imageScale150",
    "thumbnailAlignment": "center",
    "displayBreadcrumb": false,
    "thumbnailOpenImage": true
  }'>

 <a href="/uploads/gallery/F9GEO.JPG" data-ngid="ID1"  
target="_blank" data-ngdesc=""><img src="/uploads/gallery/thumbs/F9GEO.JPG" 
border="0" alt="" /></a>

    
    <a href="/uploads/gallery/zQsFE.JPG" data-ngid="ID2"  
target="_blank" data-ngdesc=""><img src="/uploads/gallery/thumbs/zQsFE.JPG" 
border="0" alt="" /></a>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily trigger it by changing the hash:

```js
$("#ngy2p").on( 'galleryRenderEnd.nanogallery2', function(){
    window.location.hash = '#nanogallery/ngy2p/0/ID1';
});
```

See working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ao3czrsw/